# construct a string and use it to call a variable

Tags: vb.net

This is probably a dumb question but I have to call one of 30 or so global variables by constructing the variable name to be called from another information. However when i do that it treats it as a string. Any ideas on how to make this work?

eg something like this:

```
Public gsNewYork As String

public sub Getinfo

dim lslocation as string
dim a as string = "New"
dim b as string = "York"

lslocation = "gs" + a + b
lblLabel.text = lslocation
```

Any ideas on how to construct the variable name and have it identified as the variable name?

Comment: Sounds like an enum might work for you.  If not, you may need to use reflection.  Neither are probably good answers, hence the comment.

Comment: I looked at reflection and I found it too hard to figure out. Im going to close this and rephrase to question as there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution to this problem is to store your variables in a Dictionary, where the strings you build are the key.